# equivalent of currentWindow.getBrowser().contentWindow; in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome

I m stuck. please help. 
I want an equivalent code of currentWindow.getBrowser().contentWindow;

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this issue recently, if you are running the code in a content script you will have access to the page's `window` object.